# Where to remove a ValueEventListener from on Firebase databse?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Let's say I have a `ValueEventListener` that listens to a certain query

```
 val reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(FirebaseConstants.ARCHIVE)
        reference.orderByKey().limitToLast(30).addValueEventListener(archiveListener)
```

Do I need to remove the listener from the query itself, like so

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(FirebaseConstants.ARCHIVE).orderByKey().limitToLast(30).removeEventListener(archiveListener)
```

or would removing from the reference object will do? like so

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(FirebaseConstants.ARCHIVE).removeEventListener(archiveListener)
```

Comment: @FrankVanPuffelen

Answer (score 2):

The common practice in Firebase is to remove the listener accordingly to the life-cycle of your activity using the following line of code:

```
databaseReference.removeEventListener(valueEventListener);
```

1. If you have added the listener in `onStart` method you have to remove it in `onStop` method .
2. If you have added the listener in `onResume` method you have to remove it in `onPause` method .
3. If you have added the listener in `onCreate`method  you have to remove it in `onDestroy`method .

But remember `onDestroy` is not always called.

If you are using `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` it means that `OnDataChange()` method executes immediately and after executing that method once it stops listening to the reference location it is attached to. So in this case there is no need to remove the listener.

Comment: I was not asking when to call remove but on which object. The ref object or the original query.

Comment: On the object on which you have added the listener, not on the "original" object. So you need to use: `reference.removeEventListener(yourListener);`